# numerical integration in mathematica given two lists of data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is there a built-in routine for doing numerical integration in Mathematica given two lists of data as `{x1, x2, ..., xn}` and `{y1, y2, ..., yn}`?

I want to do something like trapezoidal integration or others. Doesn't seem `NIntegrate` can do that. Of course I can write it on my own. Just think there are probably too many numerical integration schemes to try out, especially when I am eager to get it going.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably not what you have in mind, but you could set up an interpolation function:

```
dat = {#, Sin[#]} & /@ Range[0, 2*Pi, .1];
```

creates a list of data points (in the form of `{x,y}`).

```
fun = Interpolation[dat];
```

creates an interpolation functions (try plotting `Plot[fun[x],{x,0,2*Pi}]` to see what it is). You can then use `NIntegrate`:

```
NIntegrate[fun[x]^2, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

However, if you really want to do it the matlab way that's also possible.

Comment: Also remember you can may use _InterpolationOrder -> n_ if needed

Comment: This appears to be the recommended way, at least according to the docs. There was once an add-on package with a ListIntegrate function. Documentation for this states: "In Version 6, ListIntegrate has been superseded by Integrate[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder->k][x],{x,Max[Subscript[x, c]],Min[Subscript[x, c]]}], for data={{Subscript[x, 1],Subscript[y, 1]},...,{Subscript[x, n],Subscript[y, n]}} with Subscript[x, c]=data[[All,1]]. The default interpolation order is k=3."

Comment: As another point, some of the higher order numerical integration schemes are built on the ideas found in interpolation.

Comment: (also to @littleEinstein) Since I'm doing this right now, I'd like to add that `Integrate`, `D` & fiends support `InterpolatingFunction` objects directly.  This means that the antiderivative of `fun` can be constructed directly as `Derivative[-1][fun]`.  The result is another `InterpolatingFunction`.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that Daniel Lichtblau mentioned the same.

Comment: It also appears to be the case that while this is a general method, and gives you the antiderivative, evaluatable at any point, it is quite slow.  If all you need is a trapezoidal rule or Simpson rule, a direct implementation will be *much much* (think 100x - 1000x) faster.

Comment: @acl I mean, a direct implementation of a trapezoidal rule can be much faster than using `Integrate` or `NIntegrate` with `Interpolation`.  Suppose `data` is a list of function values, then compare `Integrate[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], {x, 1, Length[data]-1}]`, the same with `NIntegrate`, and the direct trapezoidal rule `(2 Total[data] - First[data] - Last[data])/2`.  Of course using `Interpolation` & `Integrate` is much more flexible.  (I'm using this right now, that's how it came up.)

Comment: @Szabolcs oh I see. Yes, I imagine that it'll be faster.

Comment: @acl I think a `ListIntegrate` function would still be very useful: just constructing an `InterpolatingFunction` can be slow, and very often we only want the definite integral over the complete list.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes, once I had to write functions to integrate and differentiate lists. It would be nice to have them available. Then again they are not hard to implement, so maybe that is why they're not built in.